# Multiple firebase projects auth access

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have 2 firebase projects with firestore, let's call them A & B.
Both of them have their own web clients. Right now the A web client needs to read B firestore database, so I need to allow the A client to perform certain operations on firestore under certain collections from B.
Is there a way to use authentication data from A in B to allow such operations while using firestore rules?.
Is there a way to link auth tokens from A to allow them in B?.

Any mechanism would work. The ideal would be to keep using the client web sdk in A while pointing to firestore from B and A at the same time, and reutilize the same auth for both of them. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore security rules can't look at data or accounts outside of the project where they were deployed.  You would need to route your clients through some backend API endpoint to be able to check data from multiple sources.

If you want users from A to have a sort of "automatic" account on B without having to sign in again, you can create a [custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) on B (again, using a backend you control) to let the user authenticate with the same UID with a "parallel" account in the second project.  Rules on B would still be limited to the data immediately in that account and would not be able to access anything directly in A.

Comment: Hey Doug, I appreciate your help. Thanks!. Do you think it's common to use a secondary token to validate B firestore operations? Do you think that fetching this token from a rest api endpoint would be good for security? Cheers!

Comment: My personal opinion is that it's not common to split between projects without a specific need to do so (and there is very little need to do so).  It's up to you.

Comment: @DougStevenson, Is there any way to pass either auth: AngularFireAuth, authSettings: any, objects reference to the second firebase project and will check in the Firestore rule that object? To access the second project Firestore collection database as well. Because in AngularFire V7.3.0 accepts these two objects as well while Inject the Second Firebase AngularFirestore from First Angular Project. And currently passing Null, Null?